# Flutter Text Button Ripple Effect

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm currently making an apps using Flutter for Android and facing some problem. So I'm currently using TextButton to make button in my apps and here's the code:

```
class RevisedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String descButton;
  final Function press;
  final Color color, textColor;
  const RevisedButton({
    Key key,
    this.descButton,
    this.press,
    this.color,
    this.textColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      width: size.width * 0.88,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 13, 10, 0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black45,
            offset: Offset(4, 4),
            blurRadius: 4.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
        ),
        onPressed: press,
        child: Text(
          descButton,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: textColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine except when I pressed the button where I can't seem to get the ripple effect quite right.[image]

As you can see in the pictures, when I press the button the effect won't cover the whole button itself (I'm using container to make the button body itself). I also have tried adding ButtonStyle and TextStyle with padding (EdgeInsets.all and EdgeInsets.symmetric) but sill have no luck. Any answer is welcomed, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem is related to the `color` being set at multiple places. Since the ripple effect should only cover the surface of the button and not the shadow itself, you can use the `backgroundColor` property of the `TextButton.styleFrom()` and use a `Container` within the `TextButton` itself to set the size. This should work:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 13, 10, 0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      // color: color, <-- Don't need the color here, will cause the above issue
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black45,
          offset: Offset(4, 4),
          blurRadius: 4.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: color,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
      ),
      onPressed: press,
      child: Container(
        width: size.width * 0.88, // <-- set the sizing here
        height: 50,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          descButton,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: textColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this and will be back to you with some progress :)